# Event Grid Subscription event going to delivery failure

Tags: azure-functions, subscription, azure-eventgrid

We are facing issues using below references in azure fucntion which is a subscriber to a Event Grid topic:-

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
```

All the events published are getting failed.

This was working using when i was using below mentioned assemblies.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
```

Azure function runtime ~3
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION ~3

Please let me know if anyone else is facing similar issue & solution for the same

Comment: *All the events published are getting failed.* How? Any logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable diagnostic settings for delivery failures on the EG topic, this will tell you what exactly the destination is returning (unauthorized, internal server error, etc)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/enable-diagnostic-logs-topic

You can then go from there based the information obtained.

Comment: Below mentioned is what i received:- deliveryResponse=Unauthorized: HttpRequestMessage: httpVersion=1.1, HttpResponseMessage: HttpVersion=1.1, StatusCode=Unauthorized(Unauthorized), StatusDescription=Unauthorized, ConnectionInfo=defaultConnectionLimit=1024, reusePortSupported=True, reusePort=True: "}

Comment: Good, if the answer was useful make sure to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion, I found that the Azure Function identity was not having appropriate access on the Event Grid Topic. After assigning the access the issue was resolved.