# Event Grid delivery failures when selecting Azure Function as the endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid

I am using the built in events tab under the IoT Hub to route data to an event topic. The subscriber is an Azure function (It has it's system identity enabled).

Data is routing to the event topic but the delivery is failing when trying to reach the Azure Function.

Diagnostic logs do not show anything useful:

[image: Diagnostic logs]

Event Grid Subscription:

[image: Not Found Error]

Is there a way to use this functionality even though the Azure Function has it's System Identity turned on?

I noticed this question had a similar problem and solved it using RBAC but I can't ask a question as I don't have enough reputation to comment. [Event Grid Subscription event going to delivery failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532215/event-grid-subscription-event-going-to-delivery-failure)

Any ideas?

Comment: I was facing the same issue but my messages were transferring with lag. You can use Storage Function Trigger. I think the IoT hub provides Storage integration.

Comment: @sakulachi8, yeah that's a pattern but Microsoft recommend event grid for high volume data.